# SSH to OpenShift times out

Tags: ssh, openshift

I can't SSH to OpenShift. I get a timeout:

```
$ ssh xyz@xyz-xyz.rhcloud.com
ssh: connect to host xyz-xyz.rhcloud.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

I'm not behind a proxy. Is my SSH server running on port 22?
I have a valid SSH key pair and the public key is added to OpenShift.

Thank you for your support

Comment: Did you come across the solution ?

Comment: Yes, my ISP (Comcast) blocked the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my ISP (Comcast/Xfinity) blocked port 22. Either try to change settings in the router/modem or call your ISP for support.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an environment variable TMOUT.  So, you might try

export TMOUT=

Answer (score 0):

This could be increase your timeout value:

```
unset TMOUT
export TMOUT=2880000
```